# Moodle Duplicate Course without archiving old course

Tags: moodle

A teacher is delivering the same course to two separate classes, he wants to create the course once and then copy it with a different name.

Please guide as to how duplicate a course without users, ensuring both courses are active, not archived and function independently. Thanks.

Moodle 2.8.5 Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple. Backup and restore. There is a backup link on the course menu.

https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Backup_and_restore_FAQ

Comment: Hi Russel, i tried restoring the course as teacher , but the teacher cannot create a new course from the back up. Then, what i did was, i assigned a user with course creator role,created a course,set up activities,backedup the course, then tried to restore the course. This time,i got the restore into new course option, but then got the error "error/restore_user_missing_capability". I found this issue https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-29477 , i assigned the user the permission of restore course but was still not able to restore course.Accepting your answer but please help & guide on this...